# MSVS: integral constant overflow warning in the ternary operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ternary-operator

Compiling the following code with MSVS (latest preview version with `/W3` option)

```
template<unsigned int i>
struct T { };

template<unsigned int i>
struct S : T<i != 0 ? 2 * (i - 1) : 0 /* f(i) */> { };

void foo() {
    S<0> s0;
}
```

I get a warning message:

> warning C4307: '*': integral constant overflow

`T<0>` base `struct` is correctly selected, however. It looks like the compiler tries to evaluate both, second and third, expressions. However, the Standard, *[expr.cond]/1*, reads:

> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is contextually converted to `bool`. It is evaluated and if it is `true`, the result of the conditional expression is the value of the second expression,
>   otherwise that of the third expression. **Only one of the second and third expressions is evaluated.** ...

No such warning is produced by gcc or clang. Moreover, if I isolate the ternary operator into a `constexpr` function

```
constexpr auto f(unsigned int i)
{
    return i != 0 ? 2 * (i - 1) : 0;
}
```

the warning disappears.

Is it an MSVS bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably due to the template engine, which is not used for the `constexpr` version. Do you have /permissive- activated? It also adds /Zc:twophase which has a better template mechanism.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, tried with `/permissive-` - same warning.

Comment: This warning makes perfect sense to me.